# Comment Form Validation Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, validation, comments, elementor, wordpress-theme-astra

I've got a problem with comment form validation in wordpress. Ive tried many solutions and none of them worked for me. I'm using Astra theme with elementor and I'm trying to get comment form validation without getting to this site [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTGWE.png) Can anyone help me with my problem? I've tried plugins, scripts and so on.

Everything what I could find in the internet.